# Issue with multiple desktops

Tags: macos, display

I have a mac mini with two monitors. On the main monitor I normally keep two desktops and on the second there is only one. I have been noticing that the main monitor seems to add more desktops by itself.

So I am not sure if I might be pushing some sort of shortcut to create another desktop or if there is actually something else happening.

If anyone has any ideas or if if you have had the same issue and fixed it I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: what kind does it keep adding?

Comment: @Buscar the type that you see in expose at the top - that's why I am not sure if maybe there is a shortcut in expose that I am pushing by accident to create these desktops

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18757?locale=en_US

This link explains it. Its a new(ish) feature. You can zoom to mission control (f3) or for those with a MacBook, and you have new haptic track pad, you just three finger scroll up and if you move your cursor to the top right corner of your screen you will see a plus sign appear. Click on this to add a new desktop.

You can get rid of it by Going back to mission control again (f3), where you will see all open apps, and you can just close it (them) by hovering your cursor over it and an x will appear on top left corner it, or anything else, out from there. If you're in mission control it's easy to inadvertently create additional desktops if you thro your cursor up out of your way.., I've done it a few times.

It can be super useful when you want one open for work and one for play, but that I guess is not the point. Easy to get and get rid of though. Many good publications on how to make most of the feature if you ever want to.